# Can a Changeling survive in space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

They don't eat, breathe, etc.

Can Changelings survive in space?

Could a Changeling transform into a ship and fly?

Comment: It’s kind of implied that they can — Odo was found on Bajor, but his means of getting to Bajor wasn’t, so presumably he was just sent out into space as an infant. (Which, on the face of it, does sound like a terrible idea.)

Comment: What? Odo was originally found in the Denorios Belt, the same asteroid belt the Wormhole is next to.

Comment: i think there is a limit to how large  a  changeling (founder) can turn into

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Happened a few times.

Most notably in the DS9's episode *Chimera*, where at the beginning, Odo and Chief O'Brien meet Laas. Who approached them (in a Runabout, in space) as a very fast "space eel fish"...

[image: Laas transformed into a space-resistant creature]

Comment: Is that ship travelling at warp?

Comment: @Richard no, I don't think so. I don't remember, to be honest. I highly doubt it. I can't check right now, I'm at work and I browse this place only when the code is compiling :P

Comment: We don't see Laas travel at warp, but in the Star Trek universe i can't be ruled out. We have seen space born lifeforms travel at warp. If Laas encountered one and learned to mimic it well enough he could travel at warp perhaps. We do know Changelings can shift into energy forms (fire for example). so who knows, but to travel interstellar distances he would have to.

Maybe he hitch hiked on another ship and decided to go the last leg on his own.

Comment: You say "happened a few times". I recall the episode with Odo, O'Brien, and Laas, but what were the other occasions? Did they occur on-screen or were they only on-screen references to off-screen events? In which episodes did the events or references occur?

Comment: I can't answer that. I watched DS9 6 years ago, I just don't remember.

Answer (score -3):

Changelings can morph into practically any form that matter can. Even fire. Fire is a form of energy. All heat is are excited particles of matter. (Think of how the Flash or Reverse Flash can shake their hands really fast. It can pass through anything, yet their hand is still made of matter.)

Theoretically, a Changeling could transform into a working warp core but we have no idea how that would effect them physically, or what limits they have when it comes to their manipulation of matter. Maybe fire is their limit. We don't know.

Basing what we know purely off of what we've seen on the *Star Trek* TV show, we know that there are animals that live in space and can travel at sublight speeds (think of the beings from TNG, the first episode about Farpoint Station or the Crystal Entity). I think they can even travel at a low warp. If a living being can do it, then a shapeshifter can mimic it.

Think of the show *Farscape*. A living ship. They exist in *Star Trek* too. So if there is a biological process that can create a warp field then again, a shapeshifter can copy it. What good would Laas have to turn himself into a ship if he couldn't at least travel faster-than-light? If he couldn't, then it would take him hundreds if not thousands of years just to travel from one solar system to another. Even short-distance travel would be pointless. So we know they don't eat, drink, or breath and we can conclude also that they can travel at warp or at the very least the speed of light.

Changelings can in fact travel at warp, from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.com/wiki/Spaceborne_species) and they are considered a spaceborn species.

Comment: Fire is not a form of energy